# How to validate Vaadin 8 PasswordField?

Tags: java, validation, vaadin, vaadin8

In Vaadin 7 I have PasswordField and following code:-

```
  PasswordField passwordField =  new PasswordField((String) processConfig.get("name"));
  passwordField.setWidth("100%");
  passwordField.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("[^\\s]*", "Whitespace is not allowed for password field"));
```

Recently I upgraded to Vaadin 8. Now there is compiler error no addValidator method. I know there is new Validator + Binder. But is there any way to avoid  Binder and try to have my own validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the differences between Vaadin 7 and Vaadin 8 and subsequent versions like Vaadin 14 for example. In Vaadin 8 Validators are not bound to Fields, but `Binder`. Hence if you want to validate single field without using `Binder`, the correct way is to use `addValueChangeListener(..)` and check the value in `ValueChangeEvent`.